# Facebook Application and posting to a Page Stream

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-page

As usual, I'm having problems due to a lack of clear guide in the Facebook API Documentation.

Basically I have created an application that is installed to Facebook Pages, I want to periodically post automatically via my server to the Stream of these pages <strike>(of course, willing to have it authorised, etc), but I am just unable to find how to do this. I've looked at stream write, etc, but not sure how to best make use of this. I've looked at Extended Permissions, should this simply just work for Pages? I'm experimenting but not having too much luck at the moment.</strike>

Any ideas guys? Also, am I able to make use of the new "targetting" of users that Page administrators have when posting to a Page now?

**Sorted out my previous problem, simply now wondering whether I can location target posts as Page admins are now allowed to do.**

I am using PHP with the latest library updates btw.

Big thanks!

Comment: I am able to post to my page stream from my application, however, the 'reply' is attributed to my user account and when I 'addComment' it is attributed to the page.  Did you resolve that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to post feed stories/streams is to use `stream.publish` function, check it out here:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.publish

And for automated publishing, you need to use cron job, here is how to get started with that:

http://www.aota.net/Script_Installation_Tips/cronhelp.php3